# How to use a wildcard in a batch script with CLI tools that need a specific file name?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command-line-interface

I have a cli application that doesn't like the usage of wildcards. In this example the usage of `*.dat`. I just get an error that the file `*.dat` is not valid.

I have a folder with thousands of files that need to be processed by this tool. So doing it manually is a no go. I encountered quite a few application where I had this problem but this time it's rather important. A general solution how to deal with those application would be very nice.

Can I maybe make a file list of all `*.dat` files and feed it to the application?
It's not necessary that I use batch script but it seemed like the most simple solution so far.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm assuming Windows, since you're talking "batch" scripting. You should specify this in your question, perhaps tagging it appropriately.

Comment: added but the question got also answered quite good and fast either way :)
I guess it was obvious enough.

Comment: Just good practice on SO and SU to state your OS and/or programming language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for %%x in (*.dat) do mycommand "%%x"
```

That would start the command once for each file. If you want to aggregate them you have to do a little more work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Count=0
set List=
for %%x in (*.dat) do (
  set List=!List! "%%x"
  set /a Count+=1
  if !Count! GEQ 50 (
    mycommand !List!
    set List=
    set Count=0
  )
)
```

This would pass 50 files at a time to the command. You can tweak that number if desired. The problem is if you have thousands of files in the folder, then you cannot simply list them all in a single command line (because there is a maximum command line length limit), so you have to process them in chunks.

Comment: thanks that works perfectly!
And thanks for the other one, I had a case were I would have had a great use for that. Definitely gonna save that! :)